# Trying to update driver that uses asm/system.h

Tags: drivers, 20.04, compiling

I'm trying to get an old mac mini up as a linux homepc. It's a late 2006 and I've got Ubuntu 20 running on it with a crystalhd hardware video decoder chip added on.
I've (finally I think maybe) managed to get the CrystalHD drivers installed and working.
Now I'm trying to get a taskbar indicator working. I found this one here:
https://github.com/Ardakilic/indicator-crystalhd
but when I go to "make" it, it complains about asm/system.h not being present. It's referenced in crystalhd_lnx.h and crystalhd_misc.h.

I'm not good enough at this yet to figure out where to go from here. Can someone point me to the "new" file used instead of system.h and how to update the driver to (maybe) compile? Or some alternative I can use (aside from looking at log output) to see that it's working?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your release(s).  Ubuntu uses *yy* releases only for specialist *snap* based releases for IoT appliances/devices or cloud based use (having done so since 2016). Main releases use *yy.mm* such as used by server & desktops releases.  You've tagged 20.04, but mention Ubuntu 20 (cloest being Ubuntu Core 20 or a *yy* appliance/cloud *snap* only release)

Comment: Also please clarify what exactly you are trying to build - the repository in your link appears to contain a pre-built binary program

Comment: Have you installed the `build-essential` metapackage?